# Using MathNet Library to Interpolate along a cubic spline

Tags: c#, interpolation, spline

I am trying to use the MathNet library to Interpolate along a Cubic Spline for data of various sizes.

If I run the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] xdata = new double[] { 0.083, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 2, 4, 6, 12, 18, 24, 48, 96, 192, 240 };
        double[] ydata = new double[] { 3.07525894277935, 5.17525894277935, 6.67525894277935, 7.57525894277935, 8.17525894277935, 11.8, 16.1289117118988, 19.0289117118988, 24.4536527691195, 27.8383211840501, 30.2383211840501, 36.4383211840501, 44.6247410572207, 58.3094094721513, 64.6975808035617 };
        double[] p = Fit.Polynomial(xdata, ydata, xdata.Count() - 1);

        Debug.WriteLine(Polynomial.Evaluate(0.25, p));

        xdata = new double[] { 0.083, 0.25, 0.5 };
        ydata = new double[] { 3.07525894277935, 5.17525894277935, 6.67525894277935 };
        p = Fit.Polynomial(xdata, ydata, xdata.Count() - 1);

        Debug.WriteLine(Polynomial.Evaluate(0.25, p));
    }
```

The first result is: `5.5957876536350915`.
This doesn't make sense to me as it should be close to `5.17525894277935` (second value in my `ydata`).

The second simplified result from the code above gives `5.175258942779351` which is perfect.

When I have a lot of data (as in the first example) what is the correct way to evaluate the spline to interpolate for different value of `X?

Am I supposed to break the data up into batches of three and calculate them in turn, or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot's of eperimenting with different functions, the following seems to be the correct method.

```
xdata = new double[] { 0.083, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 2, 4, 6, 12, 18, 24, 48, 96, 192, 240 };
ydata = new double[] { 3.07525894277935, 5.17525894277935, 6.67525894277935, 7.57525894277935, 8.17525894277935, 11.8, 16.1289117118988, 19.0289117118988, 24.4536527691195, 27.8383211840501, 30.2383211840501, 36.4383211840501, 44.6247410572207, 58.3094094721513, 64.6975808035617 };
var q = CubicSpline.InterpolateAkimaSorted(xdata, ydata);
        
Debug.WriteLine(q.Interpolate(0.25));
```

This gives an answer of: `5.17525894277935` which is spot on.